# Using Extended NSData Methods without Implementation

Tags: objective-c

I linked against a framework that implements extended methods on NSData.
The framework is not open-source so I don't have its implementation.

The extended methods are :

testheader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (TestObj)
- (id)test2:(id)arg1;
- (id)test:(id)arg1;
- (id)test3:(id)arg1;

@end
```

However, when I import that header file and try to use it that way:

```
#import "testheader.h"

@implementation ViewController

static void test_header_func () {

    NSData *test_var = [NSData test];

}
```

I'm getting an error says

> "No known class method for selector 'test'"

Answer (score 0):

The category provides extra *instance* methods. You are attempting to use them as a *class* method. And you are not passing the required argument.

```
static void test_header_func () {
    NSData *test_var = [NSData new]; // or some existing `NSData` instance you have
    id someResult = [var test:someArgument];
}
```